# iOS iMessage - How do I delete failed-to-sent location messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I'm using Messages app iOS `16.4.1 (a)`,
and I have multiple failed-to-sent location messages (undelivered) that I want to remove (because whenever I send or receive new messages, the failed-to-sent messages always stick at the buttom of the chat, and I cannot see the latest messages.)

I've tried the following methods, but none of them worked:

- Select multiple messages (I did that by selecting a delivered message first, but the delete (trash) button was grayed out)
- Turning off Wi-Fi and data and tap the red `i` icons to the right of the messages, there was no option to delete (No difference with Internet access.)

Screenshot:
[image]